# Bound difference of expectation values of two functions by 2-Wasserstein distance of their variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let $g$ be a $L$-lipschitz function on $\mathbb {R}^d$, and $X,Y$ be two independent random variables, then there is an inequality says that
$$ |\mathbb {E} g(X) - \mathbb {E} g(Y)| \le L W_2(X,Y) $$
where $W_2$ is the 2-Wasserstein distance.

I'm trying to understand why this inequality is true. I think I can write the left hand side as follows:
$$ |\mathbb {E} g(X) - \mathbb {E} g(Y)| = |\mathbb {E}(g(X) - g(Y))| \le L |\mathbb{E}(X-Y)| $$
Then to proof what I want, I only need to proof
$$ |\mathbb{E}(X-Y)| \le W_2(X,Y)$$
I want to know why this is true. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Since $\frac gL$ is $1$-Lipschitz, duality for $W_1$ yields  $$|\mathbb {E} g/L(X) - \mathbb {E} g/L(Y)| = \left|\int g(x)/L \;dP_X(x) - \int g(y)/L \;dP_Y(y) \right|\leq W_1(X,Y).$$

The well-known inequality $W_1\leq W_2$ finishes the proof.

Comment: Thank you Gabriel Romon !